# DayPlus seems to not work consistently with dates given as a DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

Counting days and coming up with reliable date calculations is rather essential in legal and financial applications. Unfortunately, it seems that [`DayPlus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayPlus.html?q=DayPlus) does not work as one would expect from reading the documentation with `DateObject`:

```
$Version
(* 14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023) *)

date = Interpreter["Date"] @ "January 15, 2024";
date // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2024, 1, 15}, "Day"] *) 

month = DateObject[ date, "Month" ];
month // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"] *)

DayPlus[ month, -1 ] // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2023, 12, 1}, "Day"] *)
```

How can subtracting a single day from even an arbitrary date in January result in Dec 1? Suprisingly, we find:

```
DateList @ month
(* {2024, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.} *)
```

This seems to be a bug as the granularity given for `DateObject` spoils the calculation or what am I missing? How best to avoid such issues with `DateObject` and are there other workaround than the one I found?

**Workarounds**

As a workaround we can either work with `DateList` or use `DayRound` to reference the beginning of the month for calculations:

```
DayPlus[ DateList @ month, -1 ] // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2023, 12, 31}, "Day"] *)

DayPlus[ DayRound[ date, "BeginningOfMonth", "Preceding"], -1 ] // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2023, 12, 31}, "Day"] *)
```

**Notes on consistency with regard to granularity**

The discussion in the comments and the excellent answer given by Domen below suggest that we need to clarify what "consistent treatment" of date & time is supposed to mean.

Compatible to numeric precision, it seems to me that once we forfeit on precision, e.g., by rounding, we should not be lured into a false sense of higher precision. So, when we enter a date with granularity of "Month" then the *documentation* and the *output format* should **make clear that granularity is preserved** even if we "just subtract a couple of days", i.e., we should see `DateObject[{2023, 12}, "Month"]`.

Presenting an output that is *converted* from monthly granularity back to daily granularity (see @azerbajdzan comment below) does not make a lot of sense to me, as it suggests a precision level that in fact has been "lost" and cannot be added again.

Comment: Since you defined `month = DateObject[ date, "Month" ]` then I believe `month` does not care about `day` only about `month` so subtracting one day from that date object does not care about `day` too... its precision is rounded to `month`.

Comment: I do not think so if granularity is month not day. If you need granularity day then why don't you define it that way?

Comment: I think month  granularity just means that any date is floored to the 1st day of particular month. That is why adding `0` to `30` days gives this: `DayPlus[DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"], 30]` - `Mon 1 Jan 2024`. So if on other hand you subtract `1` day which would give `Sun 31 Dec 2023` in day granularity, in month granularity it correctly outputs `Fri 1 Dec 2023` since it is floored to the first of particular month. And it is you who chose month granularity so how can you then complain the output is in that granularity? If you what day granularity then you need specify it correctly in code.

Comment: Comment on the last edit `Notes on consistency with regard to date & time`. "...and not one that suggests we are back into granularity of "Days"." In fact we are back in day granularity. If `DayPlus` gets argument that is in month granularity it computes the result in month granularity and then converts it in day granularity. So any other computation on that output is computed in day granularity (if the granularity is not changed by the code to something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the definition of [`DayPlus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayPlus.html) (*gives the date n days away from date*) is a bit misleading in such case.

I believe the simplest workaround is to explicitly put `"Day"` as the third argument (which is, however, undocumented).

```
DayPlus[DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"], -1]
(* DateObject[{2023, 12, 1}, "Day"] *)

DayPlus[DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"], -1, "Day"]
(* DateObject[{2023, 12, 31}, "Day"] *)
```

Note that the second usage is calculated using `` System`DateArithmeticDump`doDayPlus ``, while the first one is actually sent to `DatePlus` (which is handled by a kernel function). Hence, the "problem" lies already in `DatePlus`:

```
DatePlus[DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"], -1]
(* DateObject[{2023, 12}, "Month"] *)
```

By some stretch of the imagination, one could argue that this is explained in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePlus.html) (7th bullet point):

> `DatePlus[date,offset]` gives results in the same general format as date.

However, it would help to put it under *Possible Issues*.

Answer (score 4):

---

---

**Update:**

If `DayPlus` gets argument in month granularity it computes result in month granularity and then converts it to day granularity as can be seen in this code:

```
(*dimg is date in month granularity*)
dimg = DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"]
newdate = DayPlus[dimg, -1]
DayPlus[newdate, -1]
```

---

```
Jan 2024
Fri 1 Dec 2023
Thu 30 Nov 2023
```

---

---

I think that in documentation it should be more precisely explained what is meant by granularity in date objects. It is simply flooring to the begging of particular time period.

So month granularity means every date is floored to the first of particular month.
Week granularity means every date is floored to the begging of the week, i.e. Monday of particular week.

Here you can see how it works on month granularity  adding from -10 to 31 days and all outputs are floored to the first of particular month.

```
(*dimg is date in month granularity*)
dimg = DateObject[{2024, 1}, "Month"]
{#, DayPlus[dimg, #]} & /@ Range[-10, 31] // Column
```

---

```
Jan 2024

{-10,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-9,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-8,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-7,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-6,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-5,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-4,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-3,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-2,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{-1,Fri 1 Dec 2023}
{0,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{1,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{2,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{3,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{4,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{5,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{6,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{7,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{8,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{9,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{10,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{11,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{12,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{13,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{14,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{15,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{16,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{17,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{18,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{19,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{20,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{21,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{22,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{23,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{24,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{25,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{26,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{27,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{28,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{29,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{30,Mon 1 Jan 2024}
{31,Thu 1 Feb 2024}
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong edit - `DayPlus` was missing in the code after edited. Now it is correct.

Comment: @gwr: It is like with `Floor`. Would you be surprised that `Floor[1 - 0.1]` outputs `0` and not `0.9`? I guess no. `Floor` works with granularity `1`. If you want answer to be `0.9` you would need function that works with granularity `0.1`. In `DateObject` and in `DayPlus` you can set your own granularity. The `DayPlus` has just different output format as it is primarily used for adding days its format contains also `day` no matter what granularity you use.

Comment: @gwr: I agree that documentation could be more precise in description how granularity works and if outputs formats depend on granularity or not.

Comment: Yes, that is what `DatePlus` does—but that is not what it _should_ do in a consistent world, i.e., it should _preserve granularity_ (that's after all the resolution of its calculations...) until explicitly told to give an output in a different one. ;-)